# Strapi - Import and export collection types and single types

Tags: strapi

Is there a way to export already existing Collection Type and Single Type in my local and import to other Strapi environment?

Answer (score 2):

Strapi stores collection and their relations in src/api folder. So you can copy all the folders under src/api folder from the source server to the remote server and then try the import.

Answer (score 1):

you can use [strapi-plugin-config-sync](https://github.com/boazpoolman/strapi-plugin-config-sync)

It will not sync data from DB but it will sync your Collection and Single types, it's very easy to user and latest version is tested with 4.1.8.

After install make sure you do a npm run build

You will find the Plugin in admin at Settings -> Config sync -> Tool

How i use it?

Dev env, after any configuration i use Export from Config sync tool, config files are generated, i push to my branch then merging branch with the Test branch.

Test env, pulling from git then i go to Test strapi admin at Config sync Tool and hit Import

Answer (score 0):

I didnt find an official way to do this. Since I am having two copies of same Strapi configuration, so enabled git version control.

So whenever collection is added to one Strapi, I could see the configuration files under API directory of Strapi. I am pushing the same code to another strapi's code repository.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).